# Translate “Your will, My hands” into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Need help translating this from English to Latin:

“Your will, My hands”

If you need a verb for the hands, the best choice is “to do”. The point is to say that my hands will do what you want done.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Is there a verb (other than to be) implied, like my hands go wherever your will wants them to go?

Comment: @Rafael The question was just edited.

Answer (score 5):

How about **tua voluntas, manus meae**?

Comment: I like this answer, and I would love a some more detail on your phrasing and word choice!